# Raspberry Pi Pico - Install External Libraries/API

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I need to use a device to connect and control via a Raspberry Pi Pico.

The device has its own libraries and API with the commands needed to operate it, I have already done this procedure on a Raspberry Pi Zero W on Raspbian by downloading and compiling the API for this device and it works.

How can I compile or install these libraries so that the commands are recognised on the script to be uploaded to the Raspberry Pi Pico, as it does not have an operating system?

Thank you

Comment: Well, Pico IDE such as Thonny, has a package manager.

Comment: @tlfong01 thanks for the answer. My script is in C or C++ language, load script from Thonny it would be great but it seams work only using micropython